# Почему при дублировании объекта размер неточный?

Tags: unity3d

Если я дублирую 3D объект в Unity3D `(CTRL + D)`, в данном случае параллелепипед, то у меня появляются через раз в `Scale` появляются значения `.000000001`, `.000000002`, почему так происходит и что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы получили ответ на свой вопрос?

Answer (score 5):

Это артефакты чисел с плавающей точкой - особенности их реализации на микропроцессорах. На самом деле в играх ошибку в 9 разряде после запятой вы даже не заметите.

Более того, если [зайти на сайт MSDN и зайти в раздел `System.Single`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float), можно найти точность таких чисел:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решений конкретно для Unity 0, можно использоваться `System.Double`, у которых точность доходит до 17 знаков после запятой. Но для Unity это не имеет никакого смысла: скорость вычислений упадет, а двойная точность в играх попросту не нужна. Да и пересобирать свою версию Unity ради такого - задача, мягко говоря, странная.

---

**TL;DR**

Смириться и жить дальше

Comment: да и трансформы в юнити все равно будут флоаты хранить

Comment: @trollingchar можно переписать transform на double'ы, но там начнутся проблемы с графическими API и прочими прелестями собственного билда движка.